# Get JSON value from JSON which is type string in Mule data mapper

Tags: json, string, mule, datamapper

I am using Mule 3.6.1 and in datamapper I have a JSON object which is a string datatype and I need to get the value of a field from the JSON object.

How can I get this value from the JSON object while the object is of type `String`?

I cannot use the JSON transformer for this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a String of JSON and get one of its field value inside *DataMapper*, then you can utilize code like this (in *DataMapper* Script area):

```
jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject(input.jsonstring);
output.jsonValue = jsonObject.getString("jsonfield");
```

Comment: Please answer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095074/how-to-convert-managedcursorstreamprovider-to-json-object-in-mule-4

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert JSON element to a series of objects. Google GSon library is very helpful.

Example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

Gson gson = new Gson();
Student studentTest = gson.fromJson(data, Student.class);

System.out.println("Amount: " + studentTest .getStudentName());
```