# How to convert ManagedCursorStreamProvider to JSOn object in mule 4

Tags: json, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule4

How to convert ManagedCursorStreamProvider to Json object in mule.
I have written a java method which takes the Json Object as input

```
Request Payload:
{ a: "one",
b : "two"}
```

Invoke static

```
arg0 : payload
```

Java Function called using invoke static

```
public static func(JsonObject json){
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Expected arguments are [com.google.gson.JsonObject jsonObject] and
>   invocation was attempted with arguments
>   [org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider
>   arg0].
>   No suitable transformation was found to match the expected type for
>   the parameter [jsonObject].

**UPDATE:**
I have updated my java method to accept String as input.

```
"Cannot coerce Object { encoding: UTF-8, mediaType: application/json; charset=UTF-8, mimeType: application/json, raw: org.mule.weave.v2.el.SeekableCursorStream@868075a } (org.mule.weave.v2.el.MuleTypedValue@7c0c5e89) to String

1| arg0 : vars.req as String
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main (line: 1, column: 8)" evaluating expression: "arg0 : vars.req as String".
```

Comment: Why are you using GSON and Java instead of handling that payload with DataWeave?

Comment: @afelisatti Thanks for the response. I want to encrypt the request payload I have written the encryption logic in Java.

Comment: I wouldn't use a String, InputStream is more like it. Particularly if the data is coming from an HTTP operation. One thing you could also try if you have a static method in Java, is calling that through DataWeave directly.

Answer (score 2):

Mule doesn't know how to convert to a GSON JsonObject. You can use DataWeave to transform it into a Java map. Alternatively, you can change the argument of the Java method to String and Mule will transparently convert the stream to a String. Be sure to use the latest version of the Java module.

If you want to convert to a custom type of object you will need to implement it yourself in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to encrypt the request payload I have written the encryption logic in Java, but let me try passing it as String.

Comment: Please review the Updated part in my question

Comment: Is the error happening using the last version of the Java Module? Earlier versions had a bug that caused incorrect serialization to Strings.

Comment: Yes , this is the latest version of java

Comment: Sorry, I just want to confirm the version of the Java Module in the application is the latest one. Currently the version is 1.2.5 (https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/java-module). Just to be sure we are on the same page, I'm not talking about the version of the Java JDK used to execute the Mule Runtime.

Comment: The version I am using is 1.2.6